# How to move controls in TableLayoutPanel to another cell and restore it back in C#?

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I am trying to make a custom control that reacts to screen resolution.

My idea is quite simple.

To achieve that, I must be able to move controls in the cell of TableLayoutPanel.

So, I am trying to these codes below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void _btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.Height    += 30;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount  = 3;
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel4, 0, 2);
            tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(flowLayoutPanel4, 2);
        }

        private void _btnRestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel4, 6, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like working good.

[image]

This is the original image of TableLayoutPanel.

And when I press the Move button,

[image]

Yes, the tablelayoutpanel now has 3 rows and the Search and Excel buttons are in the 3rd row.

Now I have to restore them in their first place.

[image]

Here, it doesn't seem to be working fine.

I tried to send them to 6 cols, 0 row position.

But it is in another cell.

Does anyone have any idea where to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse everything you did in the `_btnMove_Click` method. The column span still being set to 2 was what was causing it to move down to the 2nd row.

```
private void _btnRestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.Height -= 30;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2;
    tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(flowLayoutPanel1, 1);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel1, 6, 0);
}
```